# Disabling map animations when the zoom is changed via the ZoomBar component

Tags: animation, here-api

Is there a way to stop animations when the zoom is changed via the ZoomBar component?

I tried `setAttributes('none', undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined)` but that doesn't appear to make any difference. I'm verifying that animations are occurring by monitoring the `transitionstart` and `transitionend` events.

Alternatively, is there a way to stop getting fractional zooms reported in the callback set by  `addObserver("zoomLevel"...)`

The animation and fractional zoom is new behavior introduced in 2.5.3 which breaks my app.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to obtain integer `zoomLevels` is to use the `Math.floor()` function. Something like:

```
 map.addObserver('zoomLevel', function () {
    if (map.zoomLevel === Math.floor(map.zoomLevel){
        // doSomething
    }
  });
```

An example of this can be found on the [HERE Maps Github Pages](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/examples.html#change-marker-on-zoom)

However observing `zoomLevel` like this is very inefficient, since the value is still changing through a multitude of fractional values and firing many times whilst updating. It would be much better to listen for the [mapviewchangeend](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Display.html#topic-apiref__Display-event%3amapviewchangeend-event) event instead:

```
map.addListener('mapviewchangeend', function (evt) {
     // doSomething
}, false);
```